# Solving $y = 2\theta - \sin(2\theta)$ for $\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to solve for $\theta$ this equation:

> $$y = 2\theta - \sin(2\theta).$$

I have tried to use the double-angle rules and $\sin^2$ rules (multiplying everything by $\sin(\theta)$) but keep going around in circles getting back to the starting point.

What is the correct way to solve this for $\theta?$

Comment: Only way is by numerics.This is a transcendental equation can't be solved with algebraic way.

Comment: See:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_function

Comment: But being transcendental does not make it algebraically unsolvable, right?  For instance, y = sin2θ is perfectly solvable.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is called the inverse radial Kepler equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation#Inverse_radial_Kepler_equation

Comment: I would recommend the bisection method, as it is more numerically stable than Newton-Raphson methods. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 4):

As said in comments, you need a numerical method.

The problem is nice since, using bounds, you have
$$2\theta -1 \leq y \leq 2\theta +1$$ Then, start at the midpoint, that is to say $\theta_0=\frac y 2$.

Let us try with $y=123.456$ and use Newton method to generate the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 61.72800000 \\
 1 & 61.47593681 \\
 2 & 61.49884687 \\
 3 & 61.49896648
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: The Newton method can be numerically unstable, since you're dividing by the derivative, which can get quite close to zero.

Comment: @AdrianKeister. I thought about it during the night. In fact,we could combien bisection steps and Newton steps such as does RTSAFE in "Numerical Recipes". Cheers :-).

Comment: Perhaps, but I still think that in this case, any derivative based method starts to look like premature optimization. If you can have more confidence in your result, and even predict in advance how many iterations you need for a desired accuracy, and the computer can run hundreds of thousands of iterations in the blink of an eye, and the coding is so easy, I don't see the benefit of a derivative based method.

Comment: @AdrianKeister. I agree with your statements. The fact that  we have tight bounds for $x$ definitely favors your point.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the bisection method, for reasons outlined in [this post](https://www.winemantech.com/blog/the-numerical-analysis-of-finding-the-height-of-a-circular-segment) that I wrote a while ago, when I was solving a very similar equation. The Newton-Raphson method, secant method, and regula falsi methods can all be numerically unstable, due to vanishing derivatives. The bisection method, while not always very fast, works extremely fast in this case because you can bound the solution (see the paper for a way to bound the solution) initially to a very small initial interval.

On modern computers, you can get $4$ to $5$ digits of accuracy in only $17$ iterations or so, which is still blindingly fast. Moreover, the bisection method is probably the most numerically stable algorithm you could use on this problem.